# Bash For Loops with Multiple Variables

Tags: linux, bash

How would I write this Linux script using a for loop? I tried

```
for i in {1..4}
do
  na$1=$(echo $na | cut -d. -f$i);
done
```

but it's not executing correctly.

```
na=$1;
ba=$2;
tff=255;

na1=$(echo $na | cut -d. -f1);
na2=$(echo $na | cut -d. -f2);
na3=$(echo $na | cut -d. -f3);
na4=$(echo $na | cut -d. -f4);

ba1=$(echo $ba | cut -d. -f1);
ba2=$(echo $ba | cut -d. -f2);
ba3=$(echo $ba | cut -d. -f3);
ba4=$(echo $ba | cut -d. -f4);

oct1=$(expr $ba1 - $na1);
oct2=$(expr $ba2 - $na2);
oct3=$(expr $ba3 - $na3);
oct4=$(expr $ba4 - $na4);

sm1=$(expr $tff - $oct1);
sm2=$(expr $tff - $oct2);
sm3=$(expr $tff - $oct3);
sm4=$(expr $tff - $oct4);

NETADDR=$na1.$na2.$na3.$na4;
BCAST=$ba1.$ba2.$ba3.$ba4;
netmask=$sm1.$sm2.$sm3.$sm4;
echo "sshd: $NETADDR/$netmask";
exit;
```

I'm getting the error:

```
bash: line 15: na1=: command not found
```

Comment: `IFS=. read na1 na2 na3 na4 <<< $na` seems a lot cleaner than multiple echoes piped to cut.  And it removes the need for the loop.  If you want to avoid bashisms and write a portable script that does not use `<<<`, write it with a heredoc: `IFS=. read na1 na2 na3 na4 << EOF\n$na\nEOF\n`

Answer (score 1):

Incrementing a variable name like this is the same thing as incrementing an array index and working with indexes is much simpler.

```
#!/bin/bash

na=$1
ba=$2

for i in {1..4}; do
  na_array[$i]=$(echo $na | cut -d. -f$i)
  ba_array[$i]=$(echo $ba | cut -d. -f$i)
done

NETADDR="${na_array[1]}.${na_array[2]}.${na_array[3]}.${na_array[4]}"
BCAST="${ba_array[1]}.${ba_array[2]}.${ba_array[3]}.${ba_array[4]}"

echo $NETADDR
echo $BCAST
```

Note that I intentionally use bogus octets to show that while this answers your question, it in no way validates the input.

```
$ ./test.sh 187.659.134.215 256.919.00a.313
187.659.134.215
256.919.00a.313
```

Oh and disregard the post about removing the {} from 1..4. That is wrong (for bash).

```
$ for i in 1..4; do echo $i; done
1..4
$ for i in {1..4}; do echo $i; done
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Not recommended, but you can use a `declare` statement:

```
for i in {1..4}
do
  declare na$1=$(echo $na | cut -d. -f$i);
done
```

A cleaner design:

```
na=$1
ba=$2
tff=255

IFS=. read -a nas <<<"$na"
IFS=. read -a bas <<<"$ba"

sms=()
for i in {1..4}; do
 oct=$(( ${nas[i]} - ${bas[i]} ))
 sms[i]=$(( tff - oct ))
done


NETADDR=$(printf "%d.%d.%d.%d" "${nas[@]}")
BCAST=$(printf "%d.%d.%d.%d" "${bas[@]}")
netmask=$(printf "%d.%d.%d.%d" "${sms[@]}")
echo "sshd: $NETADDR/$netmask"
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Most directly answering your question, you need to use indirection:

```
for i in {1..4}
do
  declare "na$1=$(echo $na | cut -d. -f$i)"
done
```

You can then access the variable with

```
name=na$i
echo ${!name}
```

Instead of the loop, you can use

```
IFS=. read -a na_array <<<$na
IFS=. read -a ba_array <<<$ba
```

This will read the contents of `$na`, splitting it into an array `$na_array` by `.`, and `$ba` into `$ba_array`. You can then access the array element at index `$i` using `${na_array[$i]}`.

Answer (score -1):

from what I understand you have a spelling mistake at na$1 in for loop, assuming it as na$i

Comment: and variables only get scanned one time, so O.P. will need to use `eval na$i=...` Good luck to all.

Comment: Changing it to `na$i` won't make it work. Assignments like that need a constant name.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't wrap your counter in {}:

```
for i in 1..4
do
   na$1=$(echo $na | cut -d. -f$i);
done
```

There seems to be a further problem with the cut command that you're using though.

Comment: `for i in 1..4` will loop once, with `i` = `1..4`. Clearly not what he intended.